# Prove the following function is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[0,b]$. Show that $$ g(x)= \int_{x}^{b} \frac{f(t)}{t} dt$$ is integrable.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ We want to show that $\int_{0}^b \mid g(x) \mid dx = \int_{0}^{b} \left ( \int_{x}^b \frac{\mid f(t) \mid}{\mid t \mid} dt \right) dx< \infty$.

Since $f$ is integrable, then we know that $ f(x) < \infty$ a.e $x$. Does this imply that $f$ is bounded for a.e $x$ ?

Also, if this is true could I use this fact to easily finish this proof?

Comment: In the problem statement, you define $g(x)=\int_0^x\frac{f(t)}t\,dt$, but your attempt seems to imply that $g(x)=\int_x^b \frac{f(t)}t\,dt$. Which is correct?

Comment: About boundedness: No. Take $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $$\int_{0}^b \mid g(x) \mid dx \leqslant \int_{0}^{b} \left ( \int_{x}^b \frac{\mid f(t) \mid}{t} dt \right) dx=\int_{0}^{b}\frac{\mid f(t) \mid}{t} \left ( \int_0^t dx \right) dt=\int_{0}^{b}\mid f(t) \mid dt.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on this $$ \int_{0}^{b} \left ( \int_{x}^b \frac{\mid f(t) \mid}{t} dt \right) dx=\int_{0}^{b}\frac{\mid f(t) \mid}{t} \left ( \int_0^t dx \right) dt$$

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Yes: Tonelli.